# How to compare a one-day count against a historic mean to identify an external change

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, count-data, discrete-data

A few months ago a client's website had some good press and their daily site visits spiked. Now, every time their traffic shows a bump, they think something external has caused it to happen. I'm trying to tell them that things can naturally fluctuate but I'd like to be able to perform a statistical test to determine if a one day change is statistically significant or not.

The simplistic way I can think of doing it is determining the +/- 3 standard deviation boundaries on the historic values and then checking if the unusual one day count falls outside that range. But is that enough to accept that something unusual (possibly external) has influenced the traffic, with 99% confidence? Is there a more robust way to identify an external factor causing a spike?